# HTML is not saving in Telerik RadEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, sitefinity, radeditor

How do I save the html formatting in the Telerik RadEditor to save in the database? I can copy and paste a web page in the Design mode window, view the HTML mode window and verify the html formatting, and click Save. Check the database, and no formatting??

Here is the code on my .aspx page

```
 <telerik:RadEditor ID="JobDescription" runat="server" Skin="Silk" ToolbarMode="Default" ToolsFile="~/Custom/Jobs/JDToolBar.xml" Width="100%"></telerik:RadEditor>
```

Here is how I am saving the value:

```
// Set the selected value 
        jobPostItem.SetValue("JobDescription", JobDescription.Content);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm looking your code and comparing it with the docs in telerik.com. I haven't found anything unusual. Could you provide more information, maybe some properties you set on code-behind?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The RadEditor is located in a custom widget in SiteFinity. The widget collects data and saves it in sitefinity as a custom content type. The form in the backend has a RadEditor too for this same field and it actually works the way you would expect. I used the Code Reference that Sitefinity gives you to create this content except I set the "JobDescription.Content"

Comment: I see... maybe there is some kind of bug. Have you tried contacting Telerik directly? I have never used Sitefinity before and maybe there is some special treatment you're missing. Sorry not to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some tips:

You should check that the value of **JobDescription.Content** is not null. If that is the case, you need to be sure that you have enabled the **ViewState** property on a page from within the Page Properties inside the Sitefinity backend, so that the values are actually persisted.

Is the JobDescription field also marked as Localizable? That would require a different syntax.

Daniel